# Is there a way to get iOS 13's new TestFlight Screenshot beta feedback into Slack

Tags: ios, app-store, testflight, fastlane, app-store-connect

Screenshot feedback is a great new feature that makes it easier for beta user to report issues (just take a screenshot)

However, reported issues are not very visible hidden away in appstore connect.  Is there an API (official or unofficial) so that they can be re-posted on slack automatically.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fastlane [spaceship] supports the download of Testflight Feedback.

See https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/pull/15793 for an example.
The downloaded feedback also contains the screenshot URL.

So you could download the image using curl:

```
curl https://tf-feedback.itunes.apple.com/bla
```

The screenshot url is in the format:

```
https://tf-feedback.itunes.apple.com/eimg/A1X/GXs/XoX/XgY/BXs/XxfKXX35jw4/original.jpg?i_for=123&AWSAccessKeyId=topsecret&Expires=1607040000&Signature=topSecretSignature
```

and can definitely be downloaded.
**But be careful:**
The urls become invalid after about one day -
therefore you should download the images immediately

Example for appstore connect feedback data retrieved via fastlane:

```
[21:32:34]: Driving the lane 'connect_feedback'
[21:32:42]:
[21:32:42]:comment: And more feedback
[21:32:42]:name: xxx yyy
[21:32:42]:email: xyz@xxyyx.com
[21:32:42]:build: 32123
[21:32:42]:
[21:32:42]:comment: This is feedback!
[21:32:42]:name: John Doe
[21:32:42]:email: email@email.com
[21:32:42]:build: 321234
[21:32:42]:     url: https://tf-feedback.itunes.apple.com/bla
[21:32:42]:     width: 3024
[21:32:42]:     height: 4032
```

Answer (score 0):

I've create a tool that can help manage the TestFlight feedback better recently. Now it is creating GitHub Issues out of the feedback, but if you want other integration (like the Slack one), you can contribute and enhance the tool. Hope it helps!

https://github.com/lukas-ruzicka/testflight-feedback

Answer (score -1):

There's no way to programmatically download these screenshots. As shown in the WWDC session "What's new with App Store Connect", the only way is to manually download it via the web interface: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/301/